# Call an External REST API from AWS Lambda

Tags: rest, aws-lambda

I'm seeing two errors in my code.I'm trying to call external API using API-Gateway --> AWS lambda

```
const getStatus = (defaultOptions, path, payload) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = { ...defaultOptions, path, method: 'GET' };
    const req = https.request(options, res => {
        let buffer = "";
        res.on('data', chunk => buffer += chunk)
        res.on('end', () => resolve(JSON.parse(buffer)))
    });
    req.on('error', e => reject(e.message));
    req.write(JSON.stringify(payload));
    req.end();
})
exports.handler = async (event) => {
   
    const defaultOptions = {
        host: event.xyz.abc.com, 
        port: 443,
        headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Authorization': 'Bearer 12345432157'
        }
    }
    
    
    var status_info = await getStatus(defaultOptions, event./userId, ''); 

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(status_info),
    };
    return response;
};
```

1.`{ "errorType": "TypeError", "errorMessage": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'abc')", "trace": [ "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'abc')", "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:16:29)", "    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1028:29)" ] }`

2.var status_info = await getStatus(defaultOptions, event./userId, '');
unexpected token `/`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many good ways to call the external API from lambda.

But there are many cases where `axios` does the job very well.

https://kuchbhilearning.blogspot.com/2022/10/call-external-api-from-aws-lambda-using.html

A short site example of the way that needs to be used with axios.